# Directshow continious capture

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture

I have Mp4 Capture Application in direct show. In my application i need to capture 30 min(or say some dynamic value) video continuously

for the I made one WaitableTimer Routine , after 30 minutes i want to stop the capture and then start again ... but after i stop capture on next sample in start capture the stream not get added to the file.  to start next capture , i have to release all the capture variables again get devices and build graph and then i can start capture.

Cant i simply stop capture , then rename the output file and again start capture?? is anything needed to add additional to do that??

Please help me on this.

Thanks

**Edit :**
Below is the graph i use for recording

```
Video Source --> x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec --------->GDCL MPEG-4 Multiplexer --> File Writer                                             
                                                        | 
Audio Source --> ACM Wrapper --> Monogram AAC Encoder --|
```

Comment: Some Multiplexer-Filters don't like what you are doing. What filter do you use? Have you tried just to pause the recording?

Comment: thanks @CPlusSharp for reply, i updated my post and added graph with filters which i use ... please let me know is any filter can cause issue on it?? and i haven't tried with pausing the recording , i'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Hi @CPlusSharp, I am not able to change the output file name after i pause the recording , i get the error : `VFW_E_WRONG_STATE` , any suggestion on that?? can we resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar to capture DV-Avi's. Have you tried to:

1. stop the graph
2. remove File-Writer
3. create new File-Writer (and configure)
4. connect File-Writer to mux
5. and start again

If this does not work then there is something wrong with the Muxer or one of the other filters. You can easily test this, just replace the Muxer with an audio and video-renderer and try to play, stop, play.

You can also just try another MP4 mux filter, like the [monogram mp4 mux](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2009/01/13/monogram-mp4-mux-0930-alpha/).

Comment: Hi @CPlusSharp , this way also does not work for me , You may be right.....  there's may be something wrong with my mux.